# ebook-convert for all .epub files in the folder

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, calibre, epub

This code converts epub file to txt file:

```
ebook-convert "book.epub" "book.txt"
```

How can I use it to convert all .epub files in the directory?

I am using Ubuntu.

#### Code

```
from os import listdir, rename
from os.path import isfile, join
import subprocess


# return name of file to be kept after conversion.
# we are just changing the extension. azw3 here.
def get_final_filename(f):
    f = f.split(".")
    filename = ".".join(f[0:-1])
    processed_file_name = filename+".azw3"
    return processed_file_name


# return file extension. pdf or epub or mobi
def get_file_extension(f):
    return f.split(".")[-1]


# list of extensions that needs to be ignored.
ignored_extensions = ["pdf"]

# here all the downloaded files are kept
mypath = "/home/user/Downloads/ebooks/"

# path where converted files are stored
mypath_converted = "/home/user/Downloads/ebooks/kindle/"

# path where processed files will be moved to, clearing the downloaded folder
mypath_processed = "/home/user/Downloads/ebooks/processed/"

raw_files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
converted_files =  [f for f in listdir(mypath_converted) if isfile(join(mypath_converted, f))]

for f in raw_files:
    final_file_name = get_final_filename(f)
    extension = get_file_extension(f)
    if final_file_name not in converted_files and extension not in ignored_extensions:
        print("Converting : "+f)
        try:
            subprocess.call(["ebook-convert",mypath+f,mypath_converted+final_file_name]) 
            s = rename(mypath+f, mypath_processed+f)
            print(s)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        print("Already exists : "+final_file_name)
```

Comment: Read `man find`.

Comment: Thnx, i tried find but something wrong.

Comment: Show us what you tried, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For files in a single directory (without recursing into subdirectories) you shouldn't need anything more than a simple shell loop e.g.

```
for f in ./*.epub; do
  ebook-convert "$f" "${f%.epub}.txt"
done
```

The shell parameter expansion `${f%.epub}` removes the trailing `.epub` so that you may add the `.txt` file extension.